# Why my login not fails

Tags: jsp, servlets

This is my servlet for Login in my JSP page. When I enter correct credentials it's working fine. If I just input username and empty password, it goes to else (invalid.jsp). But my problem is when I don't put anything for username and password or just leave username empty, my servlet fails, web page show nothing, just empty. Why is that? Please kindly explain, I already experiment and tried my best but still not working.

```
package servlet;

import bean.User;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class Login extends HttpServlet {
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    try {
        request.getSession().invalidate();

        String username = request.getParameter("user");
        String password = request.getParameter("pass");
        String fname, lname, idaccount, cat;

        Connection conn = (Connection) this.getServletContext().getAttribute("conn");

        String query = "SELECT username, password, user_type, firstname, lastname, idaccount FROM account WHERE username = ?";

        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1, username);


        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            cat = rs.getString(3);
            fname = rs.getString(4);
            lname = rs.getString(5);
            idaccount = rs.getString(6);
            // for testing int test = username.length();

            if (username.equals(rs.getString(1)) && (password.equals(rs.getString(2)))) {
                User users = new User();
                users.setUsername(username);
                users.setPassword(password);
                users.setCat(cat);
                users.setIdaccount(idaccount);
                users.setFname(fname);
                users.setLname(lname);

                HttpSession session = request.getSession();
                session.setAttribute("user", users);
                // System.out.println(test);
                response.sendRedirect("healthlink/home.jsp");
            } else {
                response.sendRedirect("invalid.jsp");
            }
        }

        rs.close();
        ps.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I mean my title Why my login fails...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's expected. If the user name is null, the query doesn't return anything, so `rs.next()` is always false, and your method doesn't do anything.

The while loop should in fact be an `if` (because there shouldn't be several users with the same user name), and there should be an `else` clause dealing with non-existing user names:

```
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
if (rs.next()) {
    // there is a user with this name. Check its password
}
else {
    // there is  no user with this name: send back an error response here
}
```

Comment: can you please post some code if possible? i'm trying to do it but the servlet still fail for me and I still want to create the beans...

Comment: o nevermind sir... I got it.. thankz... maybe i'm just tired... thank you again